# Json value in error during parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a following Json and want to print key and value.

We are receiving the data as

```
{\"dcFlag\":null,\"code\":null,\"packageQuantity\":null,\"analgesicTax\":false,\"shelfTicketName\":null,\"productType\":null,\"itemSizeValue\":null,\"unit\":null,\"unitPriceRequired\":false,\"unitPriceMeasure\":null,\"unitPriceDisplay\":null,\"itemSizeUOM\":null,\"australiaMadeGrown\":null,\"departmentCat\":null,\"categoryCat\":null,\"commodityCat\":null,\"subCommodityCat\":null,\"selectedUnit\":null,\"toConsumer\":true,\"toRetailer\":true,\"taxName\":\"1\",\"taxRate\":null,\"countryOfOrigin\":null}"
```

After JSON.parse the data is converted to

```
{"dcFlag":null,"code":null,"packageQuantity":null,"analgesicTax":false,"shelfTicketName":null,"productType":null,"itemSizeValue":null,"unit":null,"unitPriceRequired":false,"unitPriceMeasure":null,"unitPriceDisplay":null,"itemSizeUOM":null,"australiaMadeGrown":null,"departmentCat":null,"categoryCat":null,"commodityCat":null,"subCommodityCat":null,"selectedUnit":null,"toConsumer":true,"toRetailer":true,"taxName":"1","taxRate":null,"countryOfOrigin":null}
```

I tried

```
 var obj = JSON.parse(result);
                    console.log(obj);
                    $.each(obj, function(k, v) {
                        //display the key and value pair
                        console.log(k + ' is ' + v);
                    });
```

It's throwing an error as

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '455' in
```

Any inputs?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe it is already parsed?

Comment: working just fine on my end.

Comment: Have you read the error you've posted? It doesn't seem relevant to the `JSON` string you've provided. Where is _`'455'`_ in your string? Something else in your code throws this error.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `parse` as the `result` is already parsed.

```js
var obj = {"dcFlag":null,"code":null,"packageQuantity":null,"analgesicTax":false,"shelfTicketName":null,"productType":null,"itemSizeValue":null,"unit":null,"unitPriceRequired":false,"unitPriceMeasure":null,"unitPriceDisplay":null,"itemSizeUOM":null,"australiaMadeGrown":null,"departmentCat":null,"categoryCat":null,"commodityCat":null,"subCommodityCat":null,"selectedUnit":null,"toConsumer":true,"toRetailer":true,"taxName":"1","taxRate":null,"countryOfOrigin":null};
$.each(obj, function(k, v) {
    //display the key and value pair
    console.log(k + ' is ' + v);
});
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If the `result` contain backslash then it works fine:

```js
var result = '{\"dcFlag\":null,\"code\":null,\"packageQuantity\":null,\"analgesicTax\":false,\"shelfTicketName\":null,\"productType\":null,\"itemSizeValue\":null,\"unit\":null,\"unitPriceRequired\":false,\"unitPriceMeasure\":null,\"unitPriceDisplay\":null,\"itemSizeUOM\":null,\"australiaMadeGrown\":null,\"departmentCat\":null,\"categoryCat\":null,\"commodityCat\":null,\"subCommodityCat\":null,\"selectedUnit\":null,\"toConsumer\":true,\"toRetailer\":true,\"taxName\":\"1\",\"taxRate\":null,\"countryOfOrigin\":null}"';
debugger;
result=result.slice('0','-1');
  
var obj = JSON.parse(result); 
$.each(obj, function(k, v) { 
//display the key and value pair 
console.log(k + ' is ' + v); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response.I have updated the ticket can you look and suggest me thanks.

Comment: ok, i updated the second snippet please check that. It should work. You might be missing double quotes at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: Make sure of double quotes at the beginning and at the end of the string value in `result` variable.

Comment: that value is coming from thridparty.Do I need to add double quotes manually

Comment: Try adding manually. You can just use `var result = data.toString()` and check your console and tell me the error if it exist.

Comment: After anlaysing the response.I can see the double quotes at the start and end but at the start quotes there is a space and all other are started in second line is it because any hidden special character.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164758/discussion-between-ankit-agarwal-and-sree).

Comment: I have used  var data =  JSON.parse(result);
                        console.log(data);
                        for (var prop in data) {
                         console.log(prop);
                        } and it is printing numbers in the console log rather than keys